# rvest: how to follow_link an image in a webpage?

Tags: r

I need to click a link which is actually an image in the html file (the UCR logo on the top left), how should I do this?
    I have the following code:

```
url <- "http://ringmaster.cs.ucr.edu/Rings.html"
p <- html_session(url)
p %>% follow_link("")
```

The html code for the logo is:

```
 <a href ="http://www.ucr.edu/">   
<img class="pos_fixed" src="images/ucr_logo.jpg"  >   
</a>
```

I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://ringmaster.cs.ucr.edu/Rings.html"
p <- html(url) %>% html_node("a") %>% xml_attr("href")
```

Now `p` contain the url you need.

More on `rvest` http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
p %>% follow_link(css = "#container > a:nth-child(1)")
```

Have a look at `?follow_link` you can also supply *css* or *xpath* selector.
Also have a look at http://selectorgadget.com/ for how to get the css selector